# Can I automate downloading a X.509 certificate with chain?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509

Google updates a SSL Client Certificate every week or so and I need to manually download it each time. Is there a way to automate downloading this certificate?

Here are the steps I take manually that I want to automate:

1. Go to the website with the certificate (www.google.com/ncr) in Firefox
2. Click on the lock in the address bar (when you hover on it, it says Verified By: Google Inc)
3. Expand further by clicking "More Information"
4. Click View Certificate
5. Go to the details tab in the Certificate Viewer
6. Click export
7. Save certificate as X.509 Certificate with chain

I'd prefer if there was a Java or Python implementation, but I'm open to suggestions

Comment: You probably mean "server" certificate. It's not clear why you "need" to download it, but that's probably not part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using an `HttpsURLConnection`, [`getServerCertificates()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html#getServerCertificates%28%29) should give you what you want (index 0 being the server certificate itself).

`HttpsURLConnection` is a subclass of `URLConnection`. You'll get one of its instance when using [`URL.openConnection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection--), but you'll need to cast the result explicitly to be able to use `getServerCertificates()`.

If you have an `SSLSocket` or an `SSLEngine` instead, use their `getSSLSession()` method to get the `SSLSession`, and then [`getPeerCertificates()` on the session](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html#getPeerCertificates--).

Comment: VG but there is no other way to build an HttpsURLConnection, is there?